# Specifying the return type of a one-line parametric function

Tags: julia, julia-1.7

I would like to write this function:

```
is_almost_zero(x::T)::Bool where {T<:Real} = x ≈ zero(T)
```

This code, however, results in an error:

```
julia> is_almost_zero(x::T)::Bool where {T<:Real} = x ≈ zero(T)
ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[7]:1
```

Using the "full" syntax for function definitions works fine:

```
julia> function is_almost_zero(x::T)::Bool where {T<:Real}
        x ≈ zero(T)
       end
is_almost_zero (generic function with 1 method)
```

Omitting the return type also works:

```
julia> is_almost_zero(x::T) where {T<:Real} = x ≈ zero(T)
is_almost_zero (generic function with 1 method)
```

A similar working example is given in [the docs about parametric methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods): `mytypeof(x::T) where {T} = T`.

However, I would like to specify the return type, but apparently I can't. The error message doesn't tell me *which part* of the expression causes the error, but the error itself looks similar to the case where I don't specify the `where` part:

```
julia> is_almost_zero(x::T)::Bool = x ≈ zero(T)
ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[23]:1
```

So it looks like Julia doesn't "see" the `where {T<:Real}` part in my original code?

### These ways of defining the function should be equivalent, though?

According to [the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-functions), the full syntax and the "assignment form" should be identical:

> The traditional function declaration syntax demonstrated above is equivalent to the following compact "assignment form"

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481547/julia-function-declaration-style) say that these two ways of defining a function are "functionally identical" and "equivalent".

### Question

How do I specify the return type of a one-line parametric function like this?

```
is_almost_zero(x::T)::Bool where {T<:Real} = x ≈ zero(T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case I would instead recommend

```
is_almost_zero(x::Real)::Bool = (x ≈ zero(x))
```

There is no need to use `where` here.

Answer (score 5):

There's just a problem with parsing one-liners when there's a return type annotation, you can use parentheses to help the parser figure it out:

```
(is_almost_zero(x::T)::Bool) where {T<:Real} = x ≈ zero(T)
```

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks! I also found a GitHub issue from 2017 about this: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/21847